# Python logging multiple modules each module log to separate files

Tags: python, logging, module

I have a main script and multiple modules.  Right now I have logging setup where all the logging from all modules go into the same log file.  It gets hard to debug when its all in one file.  So I would like to separate each module into its own log file.  I would also like to see the requests module each module uses into the log of the module that used it.  I dont know if this is even possible.  I searched everywhere and tried everything I could think of to do it but it always comes back to logging everything into one file or setup logging in each module and from my main module initiate the script instead of import as a module.

main.py

```
import logging, logging.handlers
import other_script.py

console_debug = True
log = logging.getLogger()

def setup_logging():    
    filelog = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(path+'logs/api/api.log',
                when='midnight', interval=1, backupCount=3)
    filelog.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fileformatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    filelog.setFormatter(fileformatter)
    log.addHandler(filelog)

    if console_debug:
        console = logging.StreamHandler()
        console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-15s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
        console.setFormatter(formatter)
        log.addHandler(console)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup_logging()
```

other_script.py

```
import requests
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Comment: "It gets hard to debug when its all in one file." It will get harder when the logging is spread over several files and you don't have any way the get the entries into order.

Comment: Well its easier if my scripts are logged in different logs because each one does a specific set of tasks and when you cram them all together its hard to follow.  Especially since the main script is setting up an API so I will have multiple requests coming in at one.  Anyway doesnt look like python has a way to do what I want or at least not what I can see.

Answer (score 2):

One very basic concept of python logging is that every file, stream or other place that logs go is equivalent to one Handler. So if you want every module to log to a different file you will have to give every module it's own handler. This can also be done from a central place. In your main.py you could add this to make the other_script module log to a separate file:

```py
other_logger = logging.getLogger('other_script')
other_logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('other_file'))
other_logger.propagate = False
```

The last line is only required if you add a handler to the root logger. If you keep propagate at the default True you will have all logs be sent to the root loggers handlers too. In your scenario it might be better to not even use the root logger at all, and use a specific named logger like `getLogger('__main__')` in main.

Comment: Sweet! I think this will get me almost there.  Last one is if I have the requests module in other_script and other_script2.  Is there a way to redirect the requests module debug to the log of the script it was used in?

Comment: Define `script it was used in`. Generally this will be rather difficult to do.

Comment: well if I have requests in other_script1 and other_script2 and they both use requests then redirecting the requests module into the log of the script that used it.  Ive been trying your suggestion as well as trying to keep my def as well to have rotating logs but I cant seem to get it to work properly.  At the point where Im ready to just have one main log and deal with finding the issues when they arise.  Everything I have tried so far just seems to make things a real mess.  I dont know if you have anything else to help but if not I appreciate you trying.

Comment: btw I tried just doing it simple like you have above and nothing every shows up in the log from that module.  I dot know if the getLogger is working properly